# JavaScript works until one of the options is choosen

Tags: javascript, css

I have a page that sorts things if you choose one of the options. The list of filters was too long so I added a div that shows/hides options. On page load some of the options are hidden via CSS with `display: hidden`. Code below just changes `display` from `display: none` to `display: inline-block` based on number of clicks.

```
var timesClicked = 0;

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("filter_attribute_217").onclick = function(){
    timesClicked++;
      if (timesClicked%2==0){
        hide();
      } else {
        show();
      }
 };
```

This is show() function

```
function show(){
document.getElementById("filter_attribute_69").style.display="inline-block";
document.getElementById("filter_attribute_70").style.display="inline-block";
document.getElementById("filter_attribute_72").style.display="inline-block";

//all those other options

document.getElementById("filter_attribute_217").innerHTML = "less";
document.getElementById("filter_attribute_217").style.borderTop = "1px dashed #e1e4e6";
document.getElementById("filter_attribute_68").style.borderBottom = "none";
document.getElementById("filter_attribute_87").style.borderBottom = "none";
}
```

And this is hide() function

```
function hide(){
document.getElementById("filter_attribute_217").innerHTML = "more";
document.getElementById("filter_attribute_217").style.borderTop = "1px dashed #e1e4e6"
document.getElementById("filter_attribute_69").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("filter_attribute_70").style.display="none";

//all those other options

document.getElementById("filter_attribute_103").style.display="none";
}
```

This is working perfectly until I choose one of the options which means that some other disappear. Then when trying to use more/less button I will get errors like this one:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
    at hide (user.js?sci=481:68:50)
    at document.getElementById.onclick (user.js?sci=481:58:9)
```

Clicking it again shows the same error just with `show()` function.
I've tried checking if element exist in DOM structure with `document.body.contains(YOUR_ELEMENT_HERE);` but it always shows that all of the options exists. Checked it with

```
if(document.body.contains(element){
console.log("exists")
} else {
console.log("doesn't exist")
}
```

Console was always outputting "exists".

I then tried just ignoring the problem to see if others options will show with

```
function stoperror() {
return true;
};
window.onerror = stoperror;
```

But with the same result just without the error. I don't know why this is happening and how can I fix it. I need to add that all I can edit here is JavaScript and CSS. That's why I made another option (filter_attribute_217) and made it into my show more/less button.

### Edit

Here's HTML code for basically every option. They only thing that is changing from option to option is id and href.

```
<div data-limit="3" class="group group-filter" id="filter_attribute_104">
<h5>
Transparent
</h5>
<ul>
<li class="" style="margin-right:15px;">
<a title="tak" href="/pl/c/Balls/119/1/default/1/f_at_104_0/1">
<i src="/libraries/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1" ></i>
<span>tak </span>
<em>(56)</em>
</a>
</li>
</ul>

<div data-limit="3" class="group group-filter" id="filter_attribute_68">
<h5>
White
</h5>
<ul>
<li class="" style="margin-right:15px;">
<a title="tak" href="/pl/c/Balls/119/1/default/1/f_at_68_0/1">
<i src="/libraries/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1" ></i>
<span>tak </span>
<em>(208)</em>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I also have this in my JS code

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",(event) => {
document.getElementById("filter_attribute_217").innerHTML = "więcej";
 document.getElementById("filter_attribute_217").style.borderTop = "1px dashed #e1e4e6";
});
```

Comment: please share your html code.

Comment: there's something you are doing messing up with elements id.. maybe because you removed the elements from dom or because you maybe added elements having the same id. That error simply means getElementById didn't succeed fetching the element and the only options for that to happen are those listed before. You should really share the whole picture to make it clear (html and possibly the rest of your js code)

Comment: @SananAli edited with html code

Comment: Check my updated answer. Your question is poorly stated, so this is how far I can go with the info provided.

Comment: @GeorgeChond that answer helped enormously now I just need to tweak little things and I'm good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example with the code you provided. However your question is still not properly stated. I assume the HTML is getting generated dynamically? If so, I would make sure that the elements I'm trying to use are existing **for sure** while I call my JS. So I got rid of the `window.onload` you are using. Also, if you want to apply global changes, do not repeat the same things for each ID, just use a `querySelectorAll('.classname')` with a `.forEach`. Example:

```js
let timesClicked = 0;

let show = () => {
  document.querySelector('.group-filter').innerHTML = 'LESS';
  document.querySelectorAll('.group-filter').forEach(elem => {
    elem.style.display = 'flex';
    // Other things...
  });
}

let hide = () => {
  document.querySelector('.group-filter').innerHTML = 'MORE';
  document.querySelectorAll('.group-filter').forEach(elem => {
    elem.style.display = 'none';
    // Other things...
  });
  // Restore the first element's display
  document.querySelector('.group-filter').style.display = 'flex';
}

document.getElementById('filter_attribute_104').addEventListener('click', () => {
  timesClicked++;
  if (timesClicked % 2 == 0) hide();
  else show();
});
```

```css
.hidden {display:none;}
```

```html
<div data-limit="3" class="group group-filter" id="filter_attribute_104">
  <h5>Transparent</h5>
  <ul>
    <li class="" style="margin-right:15px;">
      <a title="tak" href="#">
        <i src="/libraries/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1" ></i>
        <span>tak </span>
        <em>(56)</em>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div data-limit="3" class="group group-filter hidden" id="filter_attribute_68">
  <h5>White</h5>
  <ul>
    <li class="" style="margin-right:15px;">
      <a title="tak" href="#">
        <i src="/libraries/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1" ></i>
        <span>tak </span>
        <em>(208)</em>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div data-limit="3" class="group group-filter hidden" id="filter_attribute_168">
  <h5>Red</h5>
  <ul>
    <li class="" style="margin-right:15px;">
      <a title="tak" href="#">
        <i src="/libraries/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1" ></i>
        <span>tak </span>
        <em>(332)</em>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```